# Android, issue with going from a GLSurfaceView to a Activity

Tags: android, opengl-es

I am very new to Android and OpenGL. I was asked to write an Android app that needs to switch between a standard Activity and a GLSurfaceView (which uses a Renderer) and the other way round. I managed to go from my Activity to my GLSurfaceView but **I did not find a way go from my GLSurfaceView to my Activity**.

I have been looking everywhere on the internet for the last two days without any luck. I am pretty sure that I am missing something very easy.

This is how I managed to go from my Activity to my GLSurfaceView:

```
Bundle extras = new Bundle();
Intent goCTestStarterIntent = new Intent(v.getContext(),CTestView.class);
goCTestStarterIntent.putExtras(extras);
startActivityForResult(goCTestStarterIntent,0);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just in case anyone is interested in the solution. My renderer extends Activity now. When the tasks on the OpenGL area are finished this code is executed: 
Intent myIntent = new Intent(context,myActivity.class);
context.startActivity(myIntent);

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand you are starting a new activity with the GLSurfaceView in it.
Now if you want to go back, simply call finish() on your new activity.

Comment: First of all thanks. I tried. It does not make any difference. The renderer keeps on rendering and my activity is not called.

Comment: I have tried to make my renderer to extend Activity and use that class functions to open my original activity. The problem I am having with this approach is that the context does not seem to return the package name. Odd! At the least for me

Comment: Just in case anyone is interested in the solution. My renderer extends Activity now. When the tasks on the OpenGL area are finished this code is executed:    Intent myIntent = new Intent(context,myActivity.class);
   context.startActivity(myIntent);

Answer (score 0):

You can't go from a `GLSurfaceView` to an `Activity`. A `GLSurfaceView` is a `View` - views and activities are different types of things. Views are shown in activities.

You can go from one activity to another (using `startActivity()`, for example), but it doesn't make sense to talk about going *from* a view or *to* a view. In Android, you navigate between activities, where each activity contains some views.

In your example "This is how I managed to go from my Activity to my GLSurfaceView", you didn't actually go from an activity to a view. What happened was that you caused the view to be shown in the activity. From here, you can make the view become invisible, or remove it from the activity, or substitute it for another view, etc. Or you can launch another activity.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying. As I said I was very new to Android and still am. You terminology is far more accurate than mine.